# How to use read_csv to read .gz file with sep='\' in python3?

Tags: python, pandas, split, gzip

I would like to read some gz files by pandas, in which data are split by '', in python 3.
If I use the code:

```
pd.read_csv('my file.gz',sep='\')
```

I will get the error "EOL while scanning string literal".
What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is an escape character. You must escape it
`sep='\\'`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
pd.read_csv('my file.gz',sep='\\') # use \\ instead of \
```

Sometimes `csv` file uses a specific separator, such as `\t` (TAB), instead of a comma(,). In this case, if the csv file use `\` as a separator, you have to use `\\` instead of `\` because `\` is an escape character.

There are many other special characters that require escape character `\`, such as `\t` (TAB), `\\` (BACKSLASH), and `\` (Single Quote).

You can see more information about ESCAPE here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp